# What does a bitwise AND do with no value infront of it?

Tags: bit-manipulation, verilog, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am using Verilog. Say you have the term:

```
& A
```

or

```
~& A
```

What does this do? Does it just compare it to an all empty array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It performs a bitwise operation on all bits of the operand

e.g.:

```
//let x = 4’b1010
&x //equivalent to 1 & 0 & 1 & 0. Results in 1’b0
|x //equivalent to 1 | 0 | 1 | 0. Results in 1’b1
^x //equivalent to 1 ^ 0 ^ 1 ^ 0. Results in 1’b0
```

More about verilog operators: [https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/verilog_operators.pdf](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Etraylor/ece474/beamer_lectures/verilog_operators.pdf)